# How to pass an input file to an input file multiple?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backend

I have a file input where the client adds an image and an img element is created through DOM, the problem is that I only have one file input and then with the submit button I want to send all the images that have been selected one by one to a file. php and upload them to the server, is there any way to go putting those files in a multiple input file and so just send the multiple input? or what would be the most optimal way?

Comment: You can not add files to an input element. So probably need to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Sounds like if you want them to add them one at a time, than you should dynamically create file inputs as they select and hide the ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with input array like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php">   
    <input name="file[]" type="file" />
    <input name="file[]" type="file" />
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Pro Tip: [Read about `multiple` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Additional_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this solved my needs to upload/save multiple images.

---

**Save this code in a file called `upload.html`:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>*Upload Test*</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="up.php" method="post" multipart="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onchange="submit()">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Save this code in a file called `up.php`:**

```php
<?php 
  $img=$_FILES['img'];
  if(!empty($img)) {
    $img_desc=reArrayFiles($img); $cnt=0;
    foreach($img_desc as $val) {
      $newname=$val['name'];
      echo $newname.' ('.$val['type'].') : ';
      
      if(file_exists('./uploads/'.$newname)){
        echo '<b>Image already exists</b><br>';
      }else{
        move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'./uploads/'.$newname);
        if($val['error']==0){
          $cnt++;
          echo 'Uploaded!<br>';
        }else{
          echo '<b>Error</b><br>';
        }
      }
    }
    echo '<hr>Uploaded '.$cnt.' images.';
  }

  function reArrayFiles($file) {
    $file_ary=array();
    $file_count=count($file['name']);
    $file_key=array_keys($file);
    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++) {
      foreach($file_key as $val) {
        $file_ary[$i][$val]=$file[$val][$i];
      }
    }
    return $file_ary;
  }
?>
```

This code was adapted from an example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#119143).